# Firebaserecycleadapter, what is the difference with "normal" recycleradapter? (android)

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have looked on the internet and I haven't find any answers.

What is the real difference between using a firebaserecycleadapter and a normal recycleradapter ?

I mean, will the Firebaserecycleradapter ONLY load data from database for what is visible on the screen? So is it some kind of a infinite scroll that only loads data if the users scroll the screen ?

I only use "normal" recycleradapter and it works perfectly. Only problem is that it loads all the data from the serveur at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, then you need to create your own custom adapter that can work with firebase database.

That's why the library `FirebaseUI` was created to make it easier to bind your data with the UI.

Also `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` updates your data in real-time.

Comment: I don't really understand because all of my own adapter works perfectly with firebase : 

I simply retrieve every data from serveur and call notifydatasetchanged() everytime I have a new data and there is not problem with that. 

It is also updated in real time because If one child is added, I just add it to my list and call the notifydatasetchanged(). 

So what's the gain for me if I use this FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: What I would like to know is :  does this FirebaseRecyclerAdapter retrieve data that you only need to see on the screen ? 

Exemple, I have 100 messages and I can only see 8 at once on the screen.
Will it load 100 messages from serveur or will it load only the 8 messages that you can see?

Comment: it will load according to your query, so if you used example `orderByChild("name").startAt("P");` then it will load all names that star with "P". It is the same as custom adapter, but only difference is you write less code. But in custom you need to do a query also..

Comment: So if I'm fine with my own custom adapter, except writing less code using the firebaseRecyclerAdapter doesn't give me anything more?

Comment: yes pretty much, less code since the library does that for you. All you need is to create an instance of firebaserecycleradapter. But, yes regarding data it is the same so dont worry on that case. Also if you use `notifydatasetchanged()` you will call the adapter to get new data, so pretty much the same.